# Wrong output with std::string using stoul, on integer array

Tags: c++, string, getline, size-t

Hi, I'm having trouble trying to convert a line of numbers, e.g.: 100 101 102, to (stoul) an dynamically allocated unsigned integer; the expected is that I can access number by number as an array, in an variable length input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <string> //Memset
int console(){
    std::string console_buffer;
    unsigned long int* integersConverted = NULL;
    unsigned int integersNumberOf = 0;
    for( ; ; ){
        std::getline(std::cin, console_buffer);
        integersConverted = console_defaultSyntaxProcessing(console_buffer, &integersNumberOf);

        std::cout << "Found the following integers from conversion: ";
        for(unsigned int debug_tmp0 = 0; debug_tmp0 < integersNumberOf; debug_tmp0++){
            std::cout << integersConverted[debug_tmp0] << " ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        delete integersConverted;
        integersConverted = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned long int* console_defaultSyntaxProcessing(std::string console_buffer, unsigned int* integersNumberOfUpdate){
    *integersNumberOfUpdate = 0;
    unsigned int integersNumberOf = 0;
    unsigned long int* integersFound = NULL;
    integersFound = new unsigned long int(sizeof(unsigned long int) * 1024);
    std::size_t stringPosition = 0;
    for( ; stringPosition < console_buffer.length() && integersNumberOf < 1024; ){
        integersFound[integersNumberOf] = std::stoul(console_buffer, &stringPosition, 10); //10 = Decimal
        integersNumberOf++;
    }
    *integersNumberOfUpdate = integersNumberOf;
    return integersFound;
}
```

I'm getting correct value if I input only one number, but the whole 1024 array is printed if I input two numbers or more and all positions get the first integer. I've tried to manually set the function std::string to constant, zero the console_buffer.length() so it finds '\0', etc; unfortunately not worked..

**UPDATE** --- 5 minutes after the topic first posting;
The problem is, as Yashas answered, at console_defaultSyntaxProcessing for loop; stoul &stringPosition returns number of characters read from, not the position of std::string.
Another problem using stoul is, if I input 100 ( 101, it doesn't work, so follows the fixed code but shall not be used.
As lamandy suggested, use std::stringstream instead.

```
std::size_t stringPosition = 0;
std::size_t stringPositionSum = 0;
for( ; stringPosition < console_buffer.length() && integersNumberOf < 1024; ){
    try{
        integersFound[integersNumberOf] = std::stoul(&console_buffer[stringPositionSum], &stringPosition, 10);
        integersNumberOf++;
        stringPositionSum = stringPositionSum + stringPosition;
    }
    catch(std::exception& exception){
        break;
    } //This catch will be used constantly by this buggy code.
```

Comment: Is there a point to all the pointers? Yet you pass std::string by value.

Comment: I've tried passing by pointer, it didn't worked either.
Pointers:
integersNumberOf_Update is to change the value directly at console() like stoul do to size_t parameter.
integersFound must be dinamically allocated as the number of integers can be very big.
integersConverted simply receives the pointer to integersFound .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for( ; stringPosition < console_buffer.length() && integersNumberOf < 1024; ){
        integersFound[integersNumberOf] = std::stoul(console_buffer, &stringPosition, 10); //10 = Decimal
        integersNumberOf++;
    }
```

does not do what you want.

You are passing the same string to `std::stoul` again and again. Your `std::stoul` function keeps reading the first number every time. When you had just one number, the `stringPosition < console_buffer.length()` caused your loop to stop. When you have more than one number, `stringPosition` will never exceed `console_buffer.length()`.

The second parameter of `std::stoul` does not take where in the string to start reading from; it gives you the number of characters processed.

For the task you are dealing with, [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) is what you need.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <array>

int main ()
{
     std::istringstream console_buffer("123 345 3 5 2 3 4 5 6 7 7  232 34 332 234 55");

     std::array<unsigned long, 1024> integerArray;
     size_t count = 0;
     while(console_buffer && count < integerArray.size())
         console_buffer >> integerArray[count++];

     for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
         std::cout<<integerArray[i] << ' ';
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god! I've trying to fix the code for almost 2 hours already, so as your answers greatly, I've fixed the code with try-catch; it is still very unstable as stoul indeed doesn't do what I need neither I understood its parameter as its my first time using it.
Main post will be updated with the fixed code, but shall not be used anywhere.

Comment: You should be using string streams. They work like `cin` and `cout`. The difference is that string streams work on a string whereas your `cin` and `cout` work on `stdin` and `stdout`. Also consider using a `typedef` for `unsigned long`.

Comment: Addendum: [The recently added `std::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) will eliminate the need for ... Well. You rendered this commend kind of pointless didn't you?

Comment: @user4581301 I wasn't aware of it. Thanks. I have anyway replaced the C-style array with `std::array`.

Comment: `std::array` is the right way to go. Only better solution might be `std::vector`. Have to see more of the Asker's usecase to be sure, though.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `std::vector` and `std::stringstream` to ease your job.

```
std::vector<unsigned long int> StringToIntegerVector(const std::string& input)
{
    std::istringstream iss(input);
    unsigned long int temp;
    std::vector<unsigned long int> results;
    while (iss >> temp)
        results.push_back(temp);
    return results;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the sample code! I will now, way smaller than my chuncky code.